# Should login tokens expire?

Tags: security, authentication, token, registration

I have developed an app including a web backend offering methods for logging in via email and password or via token. When logging in via email the server stores a token at the users record which expores after 30 days. This token can then be used for automatically logging in without needing to type in email and password again every time. At least for 30 days.

Now my question: Is it really necessary that the token expires? And if so, why?

Bye

Comment: It seems worth noting here that the notion of "token" in this question is only one of many. It differs e.g  from the widespread (and recommendable) JWTs (JSON Web Tokens), to which different reasoning and answers may apply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usability-answer is "No, it should not expire",
The security-answer is "Yes, it should definitely expire"

Why: Weak authentication and session management is number 2 on the OWASP Top Ten ([1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)). A common best practice to defend against session hijacking and other session based attacks is session expiration. This way, the impact of a stolen, predicted or brute-forced token is reduced. It also reduces the time, an attacker has to "break" the token. 
You can find a good summary on session expiration here: ([2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Expiration))

Comment: I disagree with the security answer.  I would argue that the best practice for preventing session hijacking is HTTPS.  If you can't use HTTPS (why?), you should cryptographically sign requests with either a PK key pair or a shared secret key that was shared via a secure channel.  Either approach prevents session hijacking (except for exact-replay attacks in the latter case) without token expiration, because the token is never sent over the wire in the first place and thus can't practically be compromised (unless the endpoint is compromised, but then you have no real security, and all is moot).

Comment: Even if you're using HTTPS you should still expire the token at _some point_ since you want to minimize the impact of a compromised client endpoint. Anyone with access to the machine will be able to authenticate and that can happen more often than you think, especially with laptops, tablets and phones since these are more prone to being stolen.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the security requirements of your application. Remember after someone logs into the application, someone else could come along and login using the token created for the original user.